Error when trying to install RGtk2 to R 4.3.3
Basically, I have a big R application developped on R 3.4.4 that uses the RGtk package a lot. As I need to now use some libraries like DT that are available only on newer versions of R, I am trying to upgrade the R version of my application to the newest version available (R 4.3.3). However, RGtk libraries are not on the CRAN anymore, because I think they were not updated for a long time, so I am trying to install the last updated version of that package(RGtk2_2.20.36.3).
Following the suggestions found on multiple posts and on ChatGPT, I am trying to install it using the devtools::install_github("cran/RGtk2", force=TRUE) function or by installing the RGtk2_2.20.36.3.tar.gz directly, having Rtools 4.3 installed on my Windows 10 system to compile the packages and libraries.
Mid installation, I get an error, suggesting that the problem is with pango in rtools not finding an hb.h file.
I found people having similar problems when trying to compile the GTK libraries with cmake, like here or here, but didn't quite undestand how to translate their solutions into rtools (I'm kinda new to these concepts of installing libraries from source)
I know that it might not be possible to use the RGtk library on this version of R, but I wanted to try it, as I wouldn't need to redo a large part of the code with a different library. I wanted to know if anyone has a solution for the hb.h error I'm getting and/or a different solution for using Rgtk in R 4.4.3.
Here follows the complete error message from the R Console:
C:\\Users\\e610084\\Downloads\>R CMD INSTALL RGtk2_2.20.36.3.tar.gz

* installing to library 'C:/R-4.3.3/library'
* installing *source* package 'RGtk2' ...
  \*\* package 'RGtk2' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  \*\* using staged installation
  \*\* libs
  using C compiler: 'gcc.exe (GCC) 12.3.0'
  gcc  -I"C:/R-4.3.3/include" -DNDEBUG -D_R\_=1 -DUSE_R=1 -mms-bitfields -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/gtk-2.0 -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/gtk-2.0/include -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/cairo -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/glib-2.0/include -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/libxml2  -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include -I.  -DR_LEGACY_S_DEFS=1    -I"C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c RGtkDataFrame.c -o RGtkDataFrame.o
  In file included from ./RGtk2/atk.h:4,
  from RGtk2/gtk.h:4,
  from RGtkDataFrame.h:1,
  from RGtkDataFrame.c:1:
  ./RGtk2/gobject.h:375:1: warning: 'GTimeVal' is deprecated: Use 'GDateTime' instead \[-Wdeprecated-declarations\]
  375 | GTimeVal\* asCGTimeVal(USER_OBJECT\_ s_timeval);
  | ^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
  In file included from C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/glib-2.0/glib/galloca.h:34,
  from C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/glib-2.0/glib.h:32,
  from ./RGtk2/gobject.h:7:
  C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:580:8: note: declared here
  580 | struct _GTimeVal
  |        ^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
  ./RGtk2/gobject.h:376:1: warning: 'GTimeVal' is deprecated: Use 'GDateTime' instead \[-Wdeprecated-declarations\]
  376 | USER_OBJECT_ asRGTimeVal(const GTimeVal \*timeval);
  | ^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
  C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/glib-2.0/glib/gtypes.h:580:8: note: declared here
  580 | struct \_GTimeVal
  |        ^\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
  In file included from C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-font.h:25,
  from C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-attributes.h:25,
  from C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango.h:25,
  from ./RGtk2/pango.h:8,
  from RGtk2/gtk.h:5:
  C:/rtools43/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include/pango-1.0/pango/pango-coverage.h:28:10: fatal error: hb.h: No such file or directory
  28 | #include \<hb.h\>
  |          ^\~\~\~\~\~
  compilation terminated.
  make: \*\*\* \[C:/R-4.3.3/etc/x64/Makeconf:265: RGtkDataFrame.o\] Error 1
  ERROR: compilation failed for package 'RGtk2'
* removing 'C:/R-4.3.3/library/RGtk2'


You need to install the system dependency (GTK+) first. Have you done so successfully? I think your endeavor is doomed and you should rather work on replacing the RGtk dependency with alternatives. Also, the newest R version is 4.4.0 (within a week's time it will be 4.4.1) and not 4.3.3.

I have installed the GTK+ dependencies (should've said it on the question). If I'm not mistaken, before installing it, I got different errors right at the beggining of the installation. I'll wait to see if anyone have faced this problem before and found a solution. Anyways, @Roland do you have any recommendation of a good replacement library?

I could solve the problem of installing the RGtk2 on R 4.3.3, but through another path, avoiding the error above mentioned.
Instead of using the command install_github("cran/RGtk2", force=TRUE) or trying to install the RGtk2_2.20.36.3.tar.gz file directly, I tried installing it through another source, which is normally used when people want to use the rattle package, as suggested here, but with some extra steps, as their solution didn't work right away with me and I ended up needing to do some manual installing.

Download GTK+ dependencies (gtk+-bundle_2.22.1-20101229_win64.zip file) from GNOME:
Unzip it to the path of your choice.
Set the environment variable PATH to where GTK+ was unzipped. You could use this command from within R:

Sys.setenv(PATH = "Path\\to\\gtk+")


Install RGtk2 from Togaware:

install.packages("https://access.togaware.com/RGtk2_2.20.36.2.zip", repos=NULL)


(a) Import the library:

library(RGtk2)


(b) A dialog window may appear asking you to intall GTK+. This should install some missing parts of the GTK+ or refer RGtk2 o the GTK+ installed in step 1.

Reset R.

Import the library again and you're good to go.


OBS: Solution valid for WINDOWS. Not tested on Linux or MAC.
